# IK rigging not working

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

In the file here attached i can't seem to get the IK working - the legs jump all over the place and the arms rotate weirdly when i select the pole target and i can't change the Pole angle so that the arms can go back to correct position. Same goes for the tail as i am trying to get it to wiggle but the movements i am getting are far from natural. What i am basically trying to do is to animate the xeno into a crouching position move hands and wiggle tail but i feel i am missing something small but important regarding IK system.  [image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, I don't see any IK in your armature, it's hard to tell why it doesn't work if you provide an armature that you haven't set

Comment: the legs have IK added to them (yellow bone in pic). i cant get it to work on arms and tail.

Comment: the file you share doesn't have any IK, please check

Comment: actually i've tested an IK and it works fine, except you have your Snapping option enabled and it messed up the movements, maybe it was your problem?

Comment: ugh you are right the legs now work fine it's just the tail and arms that dont work right. File reattached.

Comment: for the arm, deparent the IK controller and the IK target, parent the hand to the controller, correct the Ik pole angle

Comment: not sure what you're trying to do with the tail, the IK bone is controlled by itself?

Comment: i tried that with the arm doesnt work i must have some rotations somewhere although i did apply alt r alt g on everything, file updated .  As for the tail i want to be able to move it naturally as in like a dog tail or whatever , right now all it does is messes up the arm and the body.

Comment: again, you need to deparent the arm IK controller, otherwise there will be a circular dependency, and parent the hand to the controller

Comment: and for the tail, again, an IK bone can't be its own controller